# Does opencv implement in-place rotation or transposition of an image?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition
Seems to be a well-researched and longstanding problem, so I am a bit surprised in opencv's capabilities in solving it (zero?).

I have tried the equivalent to the pseudocode:

```
cv::Mat input(width,height,CV_8UC3);
FillMyInput();
cv::transpose(input,input);
cv::flip(input);
```

The transpose method changes the input.data pointer, so I believe the method does something functionally equivalent to the following:

```
if (input_image == output_image)
{
    cv::Mat m = CreateNewMat(sizeof(input_image));
    TransposeOutOfPlace(input_image,m)
    output_image = m;
}
```

Is this correct, and if so, does opencv expose another way to rotate or transpose an image *without allocating a large buffer with size equal to the original image?*

Answer (score 4):

It is a choice between time complexity and memory usage.

Take a look at the source code(OpenCV 2.4.10). For simplification, I remove some lines:

```
void cv::transpose( InputArray _src, OutputArray _dst )
{
    Mat src = _src.getMat();
    size_t esz = src.elemSize();

    _dst.create(src.cols, src.rows, src.type());
    Mat dst = _dst.getMat();

    if( dst.data == src.data )
    {
        TransposeInplaceFunc func = transposeInplaceTab[esz];
        CV_Assert( func != 0 );
        func( dst.data, dst.step, dst.rows );
    }
    else
    {
        TransposeFunc func = transposeTab[esz];
        CV_Assert( func != 0 );
        func( src.data, src.step, dst.data, dst.step, src.size() );
    }
}
```

Obviously, `_dst.create(src.cols, src.rows, src.type());` is the point. Function `getMat()` simply return the `Mat` header.

The OpenCV API Reference:

> **C++: void Mat::create(int rows, int cols, int type);**
>
> This is one of the key Mat methods. Most new-style OpenCV functions
>   and methods that produce arrays call this method for each output
>   array. The method uses the following algorithm:
>
> 1. If the current array shape and the type match the new ones, return
>      immediately. Otherwise, de-reference the previous data by calling
>      Mat::release().
> 2. Initialize the new header.
> 3. Allocate the new data of total()*elemSize() bytes.
> 4. Allocate the new, associated with the data, reference counter and set it to 1.

As you can see, if `_src` is a squre matrix(rows == cols), it do nothing(return  immediately). And then in-place transpose algorithm is used. If it is non-squre matrix, it will firstly allocate `total()*elemSize()` memory by using `malloc()`.

It seems to be a waste when compares to in-place algorithm. But according to Wikipedia:

> The known algorithms have a worst-case linearithmic computational cost of O(MN log MN) at best.

It is better to reduce memory usage at the cost of higher time complexity? In most case, we prefer to reduce execution time.

If want to avoid allocating large buffer, you need to implement the in-place non-squre transposition algorithm by yourself. OpenCV does not provide such tools.

Comment: That's some good analysis in the right direction, but since I've had the problem many times, I take special attention to the Mat creation functions in OpenCV. They follow a convention of <rows,cols> instead of the usual <width,height>. create(nrows, ncols, type) != create(src.cols, src.rows, src.type()); In your citation of the Mat::create method, it is quite explicit that a new Mat will be allocated, because the shape of dst (as opposed to the old dst == src) does not match. Your answer is good with some changes, as soon as we figure the issue out, maybe we should just test the peak mem usage

Comment: @Boyko Perfanov sorry for my carelessness, I have updated it.